# Cell of matrices to csv matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, cell

I have a problem converting my results to a csv file. 
My cell is like this:

```
[1403x36 double]    [1290x36 double]    [1813x36 double]    [1363x36 double]    [1286x36 double]
[1355x36 double]    [1194x36 double]    [1130x36 double]    [1277x36 double]    [1494x36 double]
[1447x36 double]    [1455x36 double]    [1817x36 double]    [1434x36 double]    [1536x36 double]
```

I want my CSV file to have (rows x  36).
I tried already cell2csv and i did a loop of fprint also, but neither of them worked. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is this a 2D cell array? What dimensions do you expect the data to be within the CSV file (i.e. how many rows and columns)?

Comment: Let's say for example all rows together with 36 columns.

Comment: Do the rows need to be in any specific order (all the top row first, then the next row, etc. or all the first column first, then the second column, etc.)? These are the sorts of details you need to include in your question. Please edit it to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with the other users who have commented, it's not clear to me what the desired structure or ordering of the contents of your CSV should be, but here is an example workflow that assumes you would be comfortable first reshaping your cell array into an Q x 1 size (in column-major order), and then concatenating the contents in each cell into an Mx36 matrix.

```
myCell = {rand(10,36),rand(5,36); rand(4,36),rand(7,36)};
myCell = myCell(:);
myMatrix = cell2mat(myCell);
csvwrite('filename.csv',myMatrix);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I think that i didn't know what i wanted in the first place. But now i get it, i should think of how my csv file should look like and then write the csv file using the Qx1 reshaping.